# mute and unmute button as3 flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to create a mute and unmute button. I don't want any play/pause button just mute and unmute. So far all I've created is the mute button, the problem is I have no clue as to make an unmute button. I'd also like the mute icon to change its appearance to unmute icon once it's clicked. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks everyone.(some side comments or explanations would be nice too)

Hope I'm not asking for too much. Here's my code so far

```
var soundReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("assets/for_flash.mp3");  
var sound:Sound = new Sound();  
var channel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();

sound.load(soundReq);

sound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);

    function onComplete (e:Event):void
    {
        sound.play();
    }

mute_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, muteSound);

    function muteSound(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        SoundMixer.stopAll();
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?  You don't know how to unmute the sound?  You don't know how to toggle an icon?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! sadly it's both.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume in your `mute_btn` instance, you have a child icon with an instance name of `muteIcon` and the presence of that icon is a visual indicator on whether your sound is presently unmuted or not (Like a circle with a slash through it type icon) and underneath that is a speaker icon.

This would be code then:

```
//First, you need to assign the result of the sound.play function to the sound channel
function onComplete (e:Event):void{
    channel = sound.play();
}

mute_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, muteBtnClick);

function muteBtnClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    //check to see if the sound channel exists yet (in case you click the button before the sound loads, otherwise you'll get an error
    if(!channel) return;

    //toggle the icon's visibility
    mute_btn.muteIcon.visible = !mute_btn.muteIcon.visible;

    //now check and see if the icon is visible or not
    if(mute_btn.muteIcon.visible){
        //it is visible, so we should unmute the sound
        channel.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(1);  //1 is the volume level from 0 - 1
    }else{
        //it is not visible, so we should mute the sound
        channel.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(0); //0 is no volume, 1 is full volumn
    }
}
```

---

Also, for efficiency, you can change this:

```
var channel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
```

To this:

```
var channel:SoundChannel;
```

Because creating a new object in that var is pointless as a whole new object gets assigned when you do `channel = sound.play();`

Comment: Hi LDMS really appreciate your help especially the explanations. I just don't understand how to do the add the child icon part. Do I create another layer inside the mute_btn to add the unmute icon? I did  that but I get an error of "Access of possibly undefined property muteIcon through a reference with static type flash.display:SimpleButton."

 Again, thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Yes, you open up your mute button's timeline, add an icon to the timeline and give it an instance name of `muteIcon`.  You'll may have to make it a MovieClip though, as I don't know if SimpleButton supports timeline children - which could be why you're getting the error.  There are other ways to do it do, like change the color of the button or the label etc.